# Xcode 4.5 - OpenGL glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: opengl, xcode4.5, osx-mountain-lion, glut

Following my attempt to learn CG and OpenGL I found [the book "Interactive Computer Graphics"](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/), which I think is a good one for beginners. Now, I'm trying to create the so called Sierpinski Gasket in 3D following the theory in the book. The project, which is in Xcode 4.5, builds fine and runs, but just when it arrives to the `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` line, it crashes and Xcode shows the error `Exc_bad_access`.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  SierpinskiGasket
//
//  Created by Federico Martinez on 24.01.13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 ParallelDev. All rights reserved.
//

#include "Angel.h"

const int NumTimesToSubdivide = 3;
const int NumTriangles = 27;  // 3^5 triangles generated
const int NumVertices  = 3 * NumTriangles;

vec3 points[NumVertices];
vec3 base_colors[4] = {
    vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
    vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
};
vec3 colors[NumVertices];

int Index = 0;
int colorIndex;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void triangle( const vec3& a, const vec3& b, const vec3& c ){
    colors[Index] = base_colors[colorIndex];
    points[Index++] = a;
    colors[Index] = base_colors[colorIndex];
    points[Index++] = b;
    colors[Index] = base_colors[colorIndex];
    points[Index++] = c;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void tetra(vec3 a, vec3 b, vec3 c, vec3 d){
    colorIndex = 0;
    triangle(a, b, c);
    colorIndex = 1;
    triangle(a, c, d);
    colorIndex = 2;
    triangle(a, d, b);
    colorIndex = 3;
    triangle(b, d, c);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void divide_tetra(const vec3& a, const vec3& b, const vec3& c, const vec3& d, int count){
    if ( count > 0 ) {
        vec3 mid[6];

        mid[0] = (a+b) / 2.0;
        mid[1] = (a+c) / 2.0;
        mid[2] = (a+d) / 2.0;
        mid[3] = (b+c) / 2.0;
        mid[4] = (c+d) / 2.0;
        mid[5] = (b+d) / 2.0;

        divide_tetra(a, mid[0], mid[1], mid[2], count-1);
        divide_tetra(mid[0], b, mid[3], mid[5], count-1);
        divide_tetra(mid[1], mid[3], c, mid[4], count-1);
        divide_tetra(mid[2], mid[5], mid[5], d, count-1);

    }else {
        tetra(a, b, c, d);    // draw tetrahedron at end of recursion
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
init( void )
{
    vec3 vertices[4] = {
        vec3(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0),
        vec3(1.0, -1.0, -1.0),
        vec3(0.0, 1.0, -1.0),
        vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    };

    // Subdivide the original triangle
    divide_tetra(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[3], NumVertices);

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );

    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points)+sizeof(colors), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(points), points);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), sizeof(colors), colors);

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                          BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );


    GLuint loc2 = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(loc2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(points)));

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); /* white background */
}

void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket Recursive");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Most of the code comes from the book. The files `Angel.h` and `InitShader.cpp` provide most of the shaders and vector utilities and they are provided by the author of the book.

What does this `Exc_bad_access` means? Is there any error in the code that could be causing this problem?

**UPDATE GDB Stacktrace**

```
(gdb) t a a bt

Thread 5 (process 60424):
#0  0x00007fff8ecce6d6 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x00007fff8e5fdeec in _pthread_workq_return ()
#2  0x00007fff8e5fdcb3 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#3  0x00007fff8e5e8171 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 4 (process 60424):
#0  0x00007fff8ecce6d6 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x00007fff8e5fdeec in _pthread_workq_return ()
#2  0x00007fff8e5fdcb3 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#3  0x00007fff8e5e8171 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 3 (process 60424):
#0  0x00007fff8ecce6d6 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x00007fff8e5fdeec in _pthread_workq_return ()
#2  0x00007fff8e5fdcb3 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#3  0x00007fff8e5e8171 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 2 (process 60424):
#0  0x00007fff8ecced16 in kevent ()
#1  0x00007fff8d6b0dea in _dispatch_mgr_invoke ()
#2  0x00007fff8d6b09ee in _dispatch_mgr_thread ()

Thread 1 (process 60424):
#0  0x00007fff8ecf03d7 in glEnable ()
#1  0x000000010000212a in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff800) at /Users/BRabbit27/Documents/COURSERA/ComputerGraphicsBook/SierpinskiGasket3D/SierpinskiGasket3D/main.cpp:129
```

**UPDATE LLDB Stacktrace**

```
(lldb) bt all
* thread #1: tid = 0x2e03, 0x00007fff8ecf03d7 libGL.dylib`glEnable + 15, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x248)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ecf03d7 libGL.dylib`glEnable + 15
    frame #1: 0x000000010000212a SierpinskiGasket3D`main + 58 at main.cpp:129
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8fd5e7e1 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

  thread #2: tid = 0x3103, 0x00007fff8ecced16 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ecced16 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8d6b0dea libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8d6b09ee libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

  thread #3: tid = 0x3203, 0x00007fff8ecce6d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ecce6d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8e5fdeec libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 25
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8e5fdcb3 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 412
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8e5e8171 libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread + 13

  thread #4: tid = 0x3303, 0x00007fff8ecce6d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ecce6d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8e5fdeec libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 25
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8e5fdcb3 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 412
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8e5e8171 libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread + 13

  thread #5: tid = 0x3403, 0x00007fff8ecce6d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ecce6d6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8e5fdeec libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 25
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8e5fdcb3 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 412
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8e5e8171 libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the crash? That's not a function I would expect to crash on its own.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to print the stack trace in Xcode?

Comment: Type "t a a bt" at the debugger prompt and that will show you all the stacks for all the threads in your application.

Comment: Sorry, should I type it just like that? If so, I'm getting this `(lldb) t a a bt
Ambiguous command 't'. Possible matches:
 target
 thread
 type`

Comment: I think I got it, check my update.

Comment: Yes, that's it. It was "thread". Sorry for any confusion. It looks like you're trying to OpenGL in a command-line app. You're calling it directly from `main()` without any window or view commands. You're probably better off starting with the Xcode project for an `NSOpenGLView`-based application and going from there.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Xcode project for a command line app, is that bad? I mean, I found the book that I mentioned in the post and I thought it was better to do a command-line project in Xcode... Do you think is better to use the `NSOpenGLView`?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to interpret/understand this `You're calling it directly from main() without any window or view commands.` I am completely new to this OpenGL(in Xcode) stuff.

Comment: How do I create the NSOpenGLView? It's under Cocoa-Application type of project? It's been so hard to learn OpenGL because of all this stuff...

Comment: Try moving the `glEnable` after the `glutCreateWindow`.

Comment: That worked !! I have another problem though but I think it's related to my own code.

Comment: Isn't it necessary that someone write an answer to mark this question as solved?

Comment: @BRabbit27 have a look to see if my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: move any OpenGL calls after `glutCreateWindow`.

Rationale: OpenGL uses a data structure called a *context*, which stores all of its internal state: textures, shaders, state settings, etc.  Every OpenGL function will access the current context before it starts its operation.  Creating contexts is a function of the windowing system you're using, or in the case of GLUT, the `glutCreateWindow` function.  What's happening in the OP is that the OpenGL implementation is effectively dereferencing a NULL pointer, and causing an exception.

That's bad form for an OpenGL implementation - most implementations will normally just have any OpenGL functions return immediately if there's not a current context.

Comment: More on OpenGL context can be found [in this link](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Intro%20What%20is%20OpenGL.html)